# Multiple signalr hubs with different configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-backplane

I am in a situation where I have multiple hubs in my project. I want to use a different HubConfiguration for each hub. This is because one of the hubs is connected up against a backplane, while the other one is not.

Basically, for one of the hubs, I have several worker processes running in other environments publishing data to it.

The other hub is basically just your standard hub, with no backplane attached.

Now, I know you can have multiple hub configurations as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623962/multiple-signalr-hubs-with-different-configurations).

Using this approach I can hook up the backplane to one of the configurations while not doing so for the other. However, it seems I am unable to specify which hubs should be available for each of the different configurations.

How do I do this?

**UPDATE:**

Basically, I have two types of applications: A standard ASP.NET application that hosts two different Hubs (HubA, HubB) and a "data collector" application that publishes data to HubA. The issue boils down to the fact that I do not know how to attach the backplane to ONLY HubA in my ASP.NET application.

I have added a diagram of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: One hub using backplane, while the other one is not]

Comment: I may not completely understand this, but why would you want to have two different Hub configurations when you should separate your datalayers on controller level (Hub level in signalr)?

Comment: In my project, I have several different applications. One of these applications is a "data collector" application, which collects data from various data sources and publishes these to a hub. This hub, is in turn, connected to a signalr backplane, so it is propagated to my ASP.NET application.

The ASP.NET application also references this hub, so it is able to publish the data from the "data collector" applications.

Howerver, the ASP.NET application also has another (complete unrelated) hub, that should NOT be connected to the backplane.

Comment: Oh, I see, I'm sure it is doable just never figured why you would couple your datamodel to the HubConfiguration instead of each independent Hub.

Comment: The question really is how though. The datamodel is in no way bound to the HubConfiguration. The only problem is how to seperate the configuration on a "per Hub" basis, such that I can have one hub that is connected to a Backplane, while the other one is not.

Comment: Added an update to the original post.